# GPS samsung galaxy s2

Tags: android

I have a samsung galaxy s2. I have some problem with the GPS. 
If I use internet my navigation works.
But when I turn the 3G off, GPS does not work.

My question is do I need internet/3G to use GPS?

Comment: if it's an A-GPS ( aka a fake GPS ), yes.

Comment: This is not a programming question, hence it should be moved to android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Assisted GPS is not fake GPS. It actually uses GPS satellites to get a fix. You are thinking about the Network provider @user827992

Comment: @Reno GPS means "Global Positioning System", if you need a carrier it's not a "Global" system, this shouldn't work in the Sahara or on the top of a mountain, it's not a GPS, it's just a funny and cheap thing.

Comment: @user827992, you are mistaken what AGPS is. "A-GPS or aGPS, is a system that can under certain conditions improve the startup performance, or time-to-first-fix (TTFF), of a GPS satellite-based positioning system." from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Comment: @Reno: no, he is not thinking about the network provider. AGPS needs both, GPS and a data connection to load correction data for the current location. He is experiencing a lack of the GPS system to revert from AGPS to standard GPS if there is no data connection.

Comment: Can someone please post a link to a solution/description? I couldn't find one.

Comment: There is always a fallback from AGPS to Standalone GPS. (Except maybe in Apple iPhone)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your GPS is set to use the "network" to identify its location.

Go to the GPS Settings and change it to use the GPS Sattelite.

EDIT:
You need WIFI or 3G to connect to the internet yes. But it shouldnt be a requirement for GPS. If you have turned on GPS sattelite, ensure you are outside, with clear sky to obtain a fix. It might just have trouble finding you with the sattelite at the moment so is resorting to the network if possible.

Comment: I did but it does not work. do i need 3G to use GPS? i read some forums but I could not get it work without internet. seems everyone has the same problem. DO I NEED 3G TO CONNECT INTERNET??

Comment: @user570593 **GPS != a-GPS**, they are 2 different technologies, with a real GPS you need just a GPS module, with a fake GPS like the a-GPS you also need to connect to the mobile network which means that you have to pay your carrier.

Comment: @user827992, you are mistaken what AGPS is. "A-GPS or aGPS, is a system that can under certain conditions improve the startup performance, or time-to-first-fix (TTFF), of a GPS satellite-based positioning system." from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS